# UITableView within UIViewController crashes when the next cell to add would not be visible

Tags: swift, uitableview, io

Firstly, I'm very new to Swift so my implementation of the UITableView is very much based on Apple's [FoodTracker][1] tutorial. I have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView. Whenever I attempt to add a cell to that UITableView that would be out of frame, the app crashes. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code for the UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TradeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var totalValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var resetTrade: UIBarButtonItem!
var currentTrade = [Card]()
var card: Card?
var tradeVal: Double = 0.0

var mainView: ViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateValue()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Data Source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentTrade.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TradeTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TradeTableViewCell

    let card = currentTrade[indexPath.row]

    cell.cardName.text = card.name
    cell.condLabel.text = cell.condition
    cell.cardValue.text = "\(cell.value)"

    return cell
}

// MARK: Functions

func updateValue() {
    tradeVal = 0.0

    for row in 0 ..< tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
        let tradeCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TradeTableViewCell
        tradeVal += tradeCell.value
    }

    let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

    totalValue.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(tradeVal)
    mainView?.updateTradeBalance()
}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func reset(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Column?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.currentTrade.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.updateValue()
    }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    }))

    presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editCard" {
        let addViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedCardCell = sender as? TradeTableViewCell {

            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCardCell)!
            let selectedCard = currentTrade[indexPath.row]
            addViewController.card = selectedCard
            addViewController.condition = selectedCardCell.condition
            addViewController.foil = selectedCardCell.foil
            addViewController.value = selectedCardCell.value
            addViewController.initialSliderVal = selectedCardCell.conditionPerc
            addViewController.initialButtonText = "UPDATE"

        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "addCard" {
        let databaseTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DatabaseTableViewController
        databaseTableViewController.mainView = self.mainView
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToTradeView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? AddViewController, card = sourceViewController.card {
        let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update the selected card.
            currentTrade[selectedIndexPath.row] = card
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath) as! TradeTableViewCell
            currentCell.condition = sourceViewController.condition
            currentCell.condLabel.text = currentCell.condition
            currentCell.foil = sourceViewController.foil

            if currentCell.foil == true {
                currentCell.foilImage.image = UIImage(named: "Images/Icons/foil.png")!
            }

            currentCell.value = sourceViewController.value
            currentCell.cardValue.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(currentCell.value)
            currentCell.conditionPerc = sourceViewController.condSlider.value
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new card.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: currentTrade.count, inSection: 0)
            currentTrade.append(card)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(newIndexPath) as! TradeTableViewCell // LINE WHERE ERROR OCCURS
            currentCell.condition = sourceViewController.condition
            currentCell.condLabel.text = currentCell.condition
            currentCell.foil = sourceViewController.foil

            if currentCell.foil == true {
                currentCell.foilImage.image = UIImage(named: "Images/Icons/foil.png")!
            }

            currentCell.value = sourceViewController.value
            currentCell.cardValue.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(currentCell.value)
            currentCell.conditionPerc = sourceViewController.condSlider.value
        }

        // Set total value
        updateValue()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        currentTrade.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        updateValue()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you added your identifier to your cell in storyboard right?

Comment: @Konsy Assuming you mean within the attributes inspector, yes!

Comment: im not sure then sir

Comment: What is the actual exception you are getting?

Comment: @conarch I got 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.' at the line 'let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(newIndexPath) as! TradeTableViewCell'

Comment: You should not be using table view cells to *hold* data.  Their purpose is to *display* data, and they consequently only exist for cells that are visible.  You should set up a datasource to hold the data for each cell.  Update that data with any changes, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should then use that data to build the cell as and when it is required (ie visible).

Comment: Based on that exception, my hunch would be that your prototype cell in the storyboard hasn't been updated to be that class.  In the storyboard, if you select the cell, then on the "Identity Inspector" (the third tab of the right side pane), the very first item, "Class", needs to be TradeTableViewCell.  Do you have that set like that already?

Comment: Also make very sure that the cell identifier's match exactly between your code and the storyboard, including casing.  I always use my ninja "copy paste" skills so that even if I typo it, at least I typo it consistently. ;-)

Comment: @conarch I do have everything set properly. I might investigate what pbasdf mentioned about not using a cell to store any data (which I am doing).